# I just want to move this login button up above the create new account and request new password. How?

Tags: users

I want to move login button up above other two options create new and request new password links. what I do I have to do. I am new to drupal

[image: LOGINPAGE FOR MY DRUPAL SITE]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I modify the login form using hook\_form\_alter()?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-can-i-modify-the-login-form-using-hook-form-alter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in your custom module and change the weight of the links

```
function MYMODULENAME_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form['links']['#weight'] = 100; //define weight as such the links moves below  submit button.
}
```

Replace "MYMODULENAME" with the name of your custom module.

Comment: Really thanks, It is the right one but forgot to clear the cache