# Remove label from login form

Tags: theming, users, forms

In my login form I have labels and other stuff I don't whant. But I'm having trouble removing them.

I already two buttons to add this in my template.php:

```
function xmed_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['register'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<a class="btn btn-default" href="/user/register">NO ACCOUNT? REGISTER</a>',
        '#weight' => 112
    );

    $form['password'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<p><a href="/user/password">FORGOT PASSWORD?</a></p>',
        '#weight' => 113
    );
}
```

And in `page--user--login.tpl.php` I have:

```
<div class="main-container container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <section class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="mainlogin">
          <a id="main-content"></a>
          <img class="class="img-responsive"" src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="logo" />
          <!--<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>-->
          <!--<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
        <h1 class="page-header"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
        <?php endif; ?>-->
          <h1>Xmed.be Stocksolutions</h1>
          <p>"We help you Xchange your stock"</p>
          <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
          <?php print $messages; ?>
          <?php if (!empty($page['help'])): ?>
              <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if (!empty($action_links)): ?>
              <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```

But how can I change the $content variable?

Comment: There is no $content variable. Do you mean $page['content']? If so $page['content'] is described in the $form array passed into your `xmed_form_user_login_alter` function. Make any changes there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I modify the login form using hook\_form\_alter()?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/how-can-i-modify-the-login-form-using-hook-form-alter)

Comment: Ok, but how can I know what attributes to use?

Comment: http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html

Comment: @Mołot No, it is not a duplicate, since the other question is not asking how to remove labels.

Comment: I am not sure why you are not using `hook_form_alter()` to alter the form instead of altering something in a template file. Template files should not have that kind of code.